# I want to validate the flags and the value using a Regex in my parameter Editor

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, user-input

Here is how the input to my application looks like.

```
-T  -a 10/06/01 -c stats,sag,cor,tra -P 0 --jsonReturn false --splash All anonymized data --prefix -3.0 --l -3
```

Here the words followed by the (--) are flags and the values following it are user inputs.
I want the regex expression to give me the values and the flags separately so I can run validations on them. Example of an error message would like this: "Invalid parameter value" and "Invalid input for the parameter value".

Here is a regular expression I wrote which gives me the flags and the values as separate groups.

```
/([^\s=]+)(?:(?:=|\s+|[^--])([^ --][\w,]+))?/gm
```

Here is a better regex expression that the one above.

```
/([^\s=]+)(?:(?:=|\s+|[^--])([^ --]+))?/gm
```

Here are some input values to test your regex.

```
-p 1 -n -1 -z zfile.csv --random false -d
```

```
--bucket null --prefix null --awskeyid null --awssecretkey null
```

Comment: there won't be anything else with `--` other than flags ?  can your filename have `--` ? or there any fixed pattern these flags will appear these will always be at the end of string or can be at any place randomly

Comment: There is a very popular package for that purpose: https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander

Comment: @Avraham Thanks for pointing me to the package. I will try that out.

Comment: @CodeManiac There won't be anything else with the -- flags. The default parameter string in the input will always appear in the format above which is
-- flag followed by a value. If you use my regular expression it gives me the flag and value as different groups. The expression is inconsistent however hence I need some help.

Comment: @CodeManiac Just for more clarity, The flags can also be returned with a single dash (-) as opposed to double dashes (--). My regular expression captures that as well but it does not capture a negative value. So it's very tedious. I am going to give the package a try. Let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: @Avraham I want to validate data in the front end through a form. Commander.js has no examples with React I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```js
/(-{1,2}[^\s]+)(\s+".+?"|\s+[^\s-]+)?/g
```

It allows you to escape dashes and spaces using double quotes, like:

```js
-p 1 -n "-1" -z zfile.csv --random false -d
// Or
-T -a 10/06/01 -c stats,sag,cor,tra -P 0 --jsonReturn false --splash "All anonymized data" --prefix "-3.0" --l "-3"
```

The double quotes are part of the value, and also the leading space, but I assume you will deal them easily.

**EDIT**

Here is a full working function, ready to use:

```js
function getOpts(opts) {
  let regex = /(-{1,2}[^\s]+)(\s+".+?"|\s+[^\s-]+)?/g;
  let flags = {};
  let match;

  while(match = regex.exec(txt)) {
    let key = match[1];
    let value = match[2];
    if(value) value = value.replace(/^\s+|"/g,'');

    flags[key] = value;
  }

  return flags;
}
```